# How can I show the shipping cost in each product on checkout page. Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to show shipping cost of each vendor in front of product at checkout page. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UE6IL.png)

**I tried with**

```
get_post_meta($cart_item['product_id'] , '_wcv_shipping_details', true);
```

But this return with blank value like:

> Array ( [national] => [international] => [handling_fee] => [national_qty_override] => [national_disable] => [national_free] => [international_qty_override] => [international_disable] => [international_free] => )

Comment: As it's returning an **array**, the last argument in `get_post_meta()` has to be **`false`** *(and not `true`)* … Also as it's returning an array of keys with empty values, that mean that nothing is really defined for your product concerning that shipping details…

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to access cart object on order details page. Once the order is placed, the cart object will get empty. You will need to get items from the object of order and then fetch shipping cost for each item.

```
// You can use this piece of code on thank you page (after order is placed)

$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

$order_item = $order->get_items();
foreach( $order_item as $product ) {
    $prodct_name[] = $product['name']; 

    // here you will get product id and you can use that to get shipping details
    get_post_meta($product['product_id'] , '_wcv_shipping_details', true);
}
```

Comment: Please tell how to do this?